# Program that teaches kids Chinese characters

Tags: python, quiz

I wrote code that chooses a random set of Chinese characters, asks the user what the characters are, and if they meet a certain criteria they level up (ex. get more than 50% correct). I want to know if there is a better way to have fewer lists, better organization, etc.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random

allnumbers = {"一": "one", "二": "two", "三": "three", "四": "four", "五": "five",
              "六": "six", "七": "seven", "八": "eight", "九": "nine", "十": "ten"}

Numbers = {"四": "four", "五": "five", "六": "six", "七": "seven", "八": "eight",
           "九": "nine", "十": "ten"}

People = {"我": "I or me", "你": "you", "他": "He or him", "她": "Her or she"}

Family = {"爸": "Dad", "妈": "Mom", "哥": "Older brother", "弟": "Younger brother",
          "姐": "Older sister", "妹": "Younger sister"}
NotLearned = [Numbers, People, Family]
Learned = []
Practiced = []
LevelOne = []
LevelTwo = []
Mastered = []
setlist = {"Numbers": Numbers, "People": People, "Family": Family}
allLev = [NotLearned,Learned,LevelOne,LevelTwo,Mastered]
all = [Numbers, People, Family]

charlist = []
set = random.choice(all)
k = set.keys()
k = random.sample(k, len(k))
outof = 0
total = len(set)
while True:
    print "Welcome! Just type in the character requested! If you want to exit, type quit."
    for x in range(0, len(set)):
        char = k[x]
        question = raw_input("Write Chinese for \"{}\" (Hint: it's {}): ".format(set[char], char))
        if question == char:
            print "You got it right!"
            outof += 1
        else:
            print "Sorry, that's incorrect"
    score = float(outof)/float(total)
    print "You got {}%. Good Job!".format(100 * score)

    if set in NotLearned:
        print "Good job learning that set!"
        NotLearned.remove(set)
        Learned.append(set)
    if set in Learned:
        if score >= .5:
            print "Good job practicing!"
            Learned.remove(set)
            Practiced.append(set)
    if set in Practiced:
        if score >= .6:
            print "Good job getting to Level One!"
            Practiced.remove(set)
            LevelOne.append(set)
    if set in LevelOne:
        if score >= .75:
            print "Good job getting to Level Two!"
            LevelOne.remove(set)
            LevelTwo.append(set)
    if set in LevelTwo:
        if score == 1:
            print "Great job mastering {}".format(set)
            LevelTwo.remove(set)
            Mastered.append(set)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this is a great idea!

#### Naming

`all` and `set` are not good names, because they shadow Python built-in names. `set` is especially bad, because it actually contains a list, which is misleading.
Also, variable names in Python should use `snake_case` instead of `CamelCase`. For example "NotLearned" should be changed to `not_learned`.

The [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) command line tool can tell you these things, I suggest to give it a try!

Also, `k` is a very poor name for a random list of characters.

#### Compatibility

It's ok if you have a reason to stay on Python 2.x, but it's still a good idea to make your scripts Python 3.x compatible when it's easy to do.
For example, you could replace `print something` with `print(something)`,
because the latter works in both versions, the former doesn't.

#### Bugs

The program has several bugs.

`outof` is not reset at the beginning of each cycle.
For example from the word set of People with 4 elements,
I "guessed" 3 correctly, got 75% score,
then in the next round I guessed 2 correctly so my score became 125% instead of 50%.
The fix is simple, move `outof = 0` inside the loop.

Another bug is in the logic to level up.
In my previous example of getting 75% score,
this happened:

> ```
> if set in NotLearned:
>     # => true => moving set from NotLearned to Learned
> if set in Learned:
>     # => true, because the set was just moved to Learned
>     if score >= .5:
>         # => true, I scored 75%
>         # => moving set from Learned to Practiced
> if set in Practiced:
>     # => true, because the set was just moved to Practiced
>     if score >= .6:
>         # => true, I scored 75%
>         # => moving set from Practiced to LevelOne
> if set in LevelOne:
>     # => true, because the set was just moved to LevelOne
>     if score >= .75:
>         # => true, I scored 75%
>         # => moving set from Practiced to LevelOne
> ```

There's a problem with logic here.
Possibly you meant to use `elif` instead of some (or all?) of those ifs.

#### Reducing the number of lists

> I want to know if there is a better way to have fewer lists

The way you use the lists, is a bit strange...
From `NotLearned`, you randomly pick one of the lists (numbers, people or family), and that list will be used for the rest of the game:
words are sampled from this list,
and the list itself is moved through other lists: NotLearned -> Learned -> Practiced -> LevelOne -> ... and so on.

Instead of moving through NotLearned -> Learned -> ..., you could use a simple number to indicate the level, and increment as the user progresses.

#### Usability

Typing Chinese is problematic if you don't have a Chinese keyboard. I played the game by copy-pasting answers. It could be more interesting and more accessible to present multiple choices that can be selected by entering their numbers.

In each cycle of the main `while` loop, the words come in the same order. It would be more interesting if the order was randomized.
See the `random.shuffle` function.

#### Unused variables

Eliminate all unused variables, they are just noise.

Comment: Thank you very much! This code is in no way complete, I just wanted to see if I was going in the right direction. This really helped, I changed the if statements for leveling up so it now works. Thanks!